# Camera + Opencv + C# take high CPU usage

Tags: c#, opencv, camera

I'm using opencv 2.4.10 (dll files) with C# (Pinvoke) to connect and read image from multi camera (Logitech C920 or Microsoft Live Camera).

After connected, it take 15~25% CPU for each camera (1920x1080 / 30fps / MJPG ) while cameras stopped and I did not read image.

```
List<IntPtr> cameras=new List<IntPtr>(); // list of cameras
for(int i=0;i<2;i++){ // connect to 2 camera
IntPtr camera = CvInvoke.cvCreateCameraCapture(I); // create camera with index
cameras.Add(camera);
}
```

My computer : Core i3 4150 3.5GHz, RAM=4GHz, OS=Windows 7 64 bit

Please help me ! What's my problem ? and how to fix ?
Thank you !

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo, but you're using `I` instead of `i`, making the index variable useless except for iterating twice. Regardless, it seems you're capturing the first camera twice, using double the necessary resources.

Comment: Hi Kody Duck ! It's typing errors (i and I).
I am using multiple cameras simultaneously to capture multiple locations and switch between cameras very fast.

If I cancel the cameras and reconnect when needed, it will be very slow.

I'm not even aware that I am not taking pictures from the camera (only connecting to them) but it takes a lot of my CPU resources.